# How to insert Spanish characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8, collation

I am trying to do a simple insert with Spanish characters without success. This is my simple MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENT PRIMARY KEY (id)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The `name` and `lastname` fields will be from Spanish people, their first and last names are like this:

- Daniel Velásquez
- Javier Ñañez
- Víctor Sánchez

But when I do the following:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO student (name, lastname) VALUES ('Víctor', 'Sanchez');
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xA1ctor' for column 'name' at row
1
```

Well, I am really confused about collations, encondings and everything related when doing a search on internet.

So, what is the correct way to deal with this? Just to know I am using PHP and I know that a way to retrieve some special characters is using `htmlentities($value);`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the field collation to latin1_swedish_ci?

Comment: @Battle_707 You gave me a little hint, I solved this just specifying the charset when starting mysql using "charset latin1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a look at this

it will help you

[Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

this is about the encoding [character encoding](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1):

When you start mysql, specify Unicode:

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just saved the file with Sublime Editor and at the menu saving the file I chose the save with encoding and selected UTF8 and it solved the problem for my case. I used the same encoding and collation as you. It was a encoding problem with the file.